# Fail to restTemplate create with @PowerMockIgnore in powermock

Tags: java, junit4, powermock, powermockito

I need a powermock for private method test.
It is working well if I use only @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) without @PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class).

I need to use @PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) for @autowired.
But It doesn't fail to start.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyConfig.class}) 
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringPowerMockTest {

}
```

Error's detail

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder (in unnamed module @0x45d84a20) cannot access class jdk.xml.internal.SecuritySupport (in module java.xml) because module java.xml does not export jdk.xml.internal to unnamed module @0x45d84a20
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.(FactoryFinder.java:69)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:147)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.buildSaxParser(SaxEventRecorder.java:79)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.recordEvents(SaxEventRecorder.java:57)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:151)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:417)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:362)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:99)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.createInstance(WhiteboxImpl.java:1414)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeConstructor(WhiteboxImpl.java:1262)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeConstructor(Whitebox.java:497)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$1.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:101)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$1.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.withContextClassLoader(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:132)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.createDelegate(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:96)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:165)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:47)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:69)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:36)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Threfore I add this through https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/864

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyConfig.class}) 
// I added this
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.net.ssl.*", "org.slf4j.*", "javax.parsers.*", "ch.qos.logback.*", 
"jdk.xml.internal.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", 
"javax.management.*"})
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringPowerMockTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
      //success
    }

}
```

It was working well.

Therefore, I started to write code for test

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyConfig.class}) 
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.net.ssl.*", "org.slf4j.*", "javax.parsers.*", "ch.qos.logback.*", 
"jdk.xml.internal.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", 
"javax.management.*"})
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringPowerMockTest {

    @Test
    public void initalize() throws IOException {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        .....
    }


}
```

But I couldn't start with this error message

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.xml/javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:181)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:257)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(TransformerFactory.java:126)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.(AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter.(AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter.java:38)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.(Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.(RestTemplate.java:161)
    at com.nesic.mroc.elevator.SpringPowerMockTest.initalize(SpringPowerMockTest.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$2.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:149)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$2.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:141)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.withContextClassLoader(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:132)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.run(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:141)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:169)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl (in unnamed module @0x10d5ba8d) cannot access class jdk.xml.internal.JdkXmlUtils (in module java.xml) because module java.xml does not export jdk.xml.internal to unnamed module @0x10d5ba8d
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:251)
    ... 52 more
```

my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-beta.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-beta.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
        <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I don't know why I can't create RestTempleate. and I don't know @PowerMockIgnore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that though adding code under line. But I can't understand what was cause.

```
com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.*
```

This is code which powermock a method

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.*;

import java.io.File;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;


@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(PowerMockTarget.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "javax.xml.transform.*", "org.xml.*", "javax.management.*", "javax.net.ssl.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.*"})
public class PowerMockTest {

    @Test
    public void mockStaticMethod() throws Exception {
        File fileMock = mock(File.class);
        when(fileMock.exists()).thenReturn(true);

        whenNew(File.class.getConstructor(String.class)).withArguments(anyString()).thenReturn(fileMock);
        
        PowerMockTarget target = new PowerMockTarget();
        assertEquals(target.isFileExist(), true);

        assertEquals("My bean message", message.getContent());
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class MessageForTest{
    private long id;
    private String content;
    
}


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class MessageForTest{
    private long id;
    private String content;
    
}
```

Powermocked target code.

```
import java.io.File;

public class PowerMockTarget {

    public boolean isFileExist() {
    
        if(!new File("filename").exists()) {
          throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```